# Отправка данных на SQL Server с помощью службы Windows

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ftp, wcf

Требуется написать приложение, которое будет находится на сервере. Приложение должно обратиться к FTP, проверить есть ли там Json файл, если есть, то десериализовать его и отправить на SQL Server.
Для реализации я решил выбрать службы Windows, чтобы программа постоянно работала и обращалась к FTP в момент, когда там появляется новый файл. 
Проблема в том, что я не могу отправить десериализованный объект в бд, хотя подключение правильное. Если это подключение реализовать в простом консольном приложении, то все отрабатывает отлично. А в службе ошибка

```
SqlException: Не удается открыть базу данных "userdb", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход.
При входе в систему пользователя "WORKGROUP\DESKTOP" произошла ошибка.
```

```
ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("путь к файлу");
OpenTrunk restoredPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenTrunk>(jsonString);
db.OpenTrunks.Add(restoredPerson);
db.SaveChanges();
File.Delete("путь к файлу");
```

```
  public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<OpenTrunk> OpenTrunks { get; set; }

        public ApplicationContext() : base("DbConnection")
        {

        }
    }
```

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=.\;Database=EngineeringCalculator;Integrated Security=True;"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно. Подключение идет с авторизацией текущего пользователя, у вас сервис запускается под учеткой `WORKGROUP\DESKTOP`, которая, похоже, не имеет прав доступа к целевой БД.
Варианты решения:

- В настройках службы указываете пользователя под которым будет работать служба, затем данному пользователю предоставляете права доступа к БД;
- В строке подключения указываете пользователя и пароль, и подключаетесь с помощью аутентификации SQL;
- Дать права к БД пользователю `WORKGROUP\DESKTOP` тоже можно, но мне этот способ не нравится - он будет работать только если служба и все ресурсы - папка FTP, БД - на одном компьютере.

Comment: Спасибо. Я указал в строке подключения пользователя и пароль и это помогло мне.